# Add more context to Exception or Error in Groovy

Tags: exception, groovy

When I want just to add more context to any exception that has happened (including parsing errors and even out of memory) I write code as follows

```
    try {
        new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
    } catch (any) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot parse response:\n$response", any)
    }
```

This works fine, but I may end up with `OutOfMemoryError` being wrapped in `IllegalStateException` which doesn't sound right, as further there could be dedicated exception handling mechanism just for `Error` throwables.

Is there any way to just add more context to exception and still preserve its original type or category? I.e. when I get `OOME`, I want to rethrow `Error`, when I get some parsing exception, I want to rethrow some unchecked exception etc. And of course I don't want to do it manually for each category, as `OOME` is pretty unlikely and I don't want to produce special code for corner cases (while still I want to be technically correct).

Comment: I would strongly suggest not doing the thing you are trying to do. There are various reasons. Consider the following scenarios. What if the `response` holds 2 GB of incorrect data? Do you want to log it? What if your application uses some remote logger - do you want to use your network to transfer 2 GB of the data instead of handling your customer requests? What if the JSON response contains some sensitive data? I don't know the context, but what you ask for sounds suspicious. The parsing exception usually provides some useful context that should allow investigating the problem.

Comment: In my context there are no sensitive data. If something returns 2GB of incorrect data, I want to make an effort and try to log it for investigation purposes. For me it's better than no data for investigation. In general I agree, that such code should be avoided in generic library, but in my code this is what I expect.

Comment: I get your point, and I agree that having data for the investigation is essential. However, it doesn't justify using exceptions for that. Think about it differently. You can catch any exception, dump the response to file (or DB), log that the error happened and the data for investigation is dumped (you can generate sha1sum from the JSON response and make sure you dump the response only once), and finally - rethrow the exception you caught earlier. Of course, dumping a response may fail, so you need to think about it upfront. Such implementation is explicit and can be encapsulated nicely.

Comment: Yeah, what you propose sounds like solid solution, but requires additional coding and testing. In my case vast majority of responses will be really small (I control them), so I'd like to pass them directly in exception to have one jump less during investigations.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this in groovy by using its [metaprogramming](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html) features. In particular, for your case [metaclasses](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_per_instance_metaclass) provides everything you need. Using them you can dynamically add/attach a `contextData` object to the `exception` you want it to carry around:

```
    private static void throwsEnhancedException() throws IOException {
        try {
            throwsBasicException()
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.metaClass.contextData = "My context data"
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Then to retrieve this `contextData` in other parts of the code, just inspect the `exception` object like this:

```
    private static void doSomethingWithContextData(Closure contextDataHandler) throws IOException {
        try {
            throwsEnhancedException();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // RETRIEVE `contextData` FROM `e` OR NULL IF THE PROPERTY DO NOT EXIST
            def contextData = e.hasProperty('contextData')?.getProperty(e)

            // DO SOMETHING WITH `contextData`
            contextDataHandler(contextData)
        }
    }
```

There I am using the argument `contextDataHandler` as a groovy [`Closure`](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) to handle `contextData` in a flexible manner.

The following is a full working demo of this:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

class ExceptionEnhancer {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def logger = { println "${LocalDateTime.now()} - Context Data = [$it]" }
        doSomethingWithContextData logger
    }

    private static void doSomethingWithContextData(Closure contextDataHandler) throws IOException {
        try {
            throwsEnhancedException();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // RETRIEVE `contextData` FROM `e` OR NULL IF THE PROPERTY DO NOT EXIST
            def contextData = e.hasProperty('contextData')?.getProperty(e)

            // DO SOMETHING WITH `contextData`
            contextDataHandler(contextData)
        }
    }
    
    private static void throwsEnhancedException() throws IOException {
        try {
            throwsBasicException()
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.metaClass.contextData = "My context data"
            throw e;
        }
    }
    
    public static void throwsBasicException() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/groovy/so/a56202268)

Hope this helps.